# How to generate an autonumber in excel based on Group of Column Value

Tags: excel, vba

I am clueless what to do. Any help would be great.
I have two columns Name and Revision and based on both column I have to generate Auto Number. If Name has 3 revisions then there should be only one Number.
Below is the example for reference.

```
Name         Revision   Auto Number
18FC1C4AA110    1          1001
0386FCC1A155    1          1002
CA648070ADA7    1          1003
CA648070ADA7    2          1003
8B488B4A988F    1          1004
CE128EDA6B84    1          1005
3CF6F8CE501A    4          1006
3CF6F8CE501A    3          1006
3CF6F8CE501A    2          1006
3CF6F8CE501A    1          1006
A0EEF6FADEF3    1          1007
BAC53A2342DE    1          1008
AC95502EA3CD    2          1009
AC95502EA3CD    1          1009
7DCB09E99F54    2          10010
```

Thanks.

Comment: Quickly edit and rephrase your question, or it will be downvoted severely very fast. Read the guidelines http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask P.S. I didn't downvote, but I probably should have.

Comment: Thanks. rephrased it.

Comment: I think one of the main things that @Miqi180 was referring to was the fact that you aren't showing what code you have tried so far, and what errors that code is producing or how the code isn't doing what is required.

Comment: I'm not following. It seems like `revision` has no impact on the `autonumber`. Merely that each distinct `name` get it's own number regardless of revision. Is that right?

Comment: P.S.  If your data is arranged so that all the occurrences of each name appear together (as seems to be the case in your sample), then all you are trying to do is "In column C, create a number equal to the number above plus [if the value in this row's column A is the same as the value in the previous row's column A, then 0 else 1]" - which really does **not** require VBA.

Comment: As @YowE3K suggests, assuming your data is in `A1`, then: `=IF(A2<>A1, C1+1, C1)` would work fine for you needs.

Comment: You should try and post some code with your question.  In my answer I also apply a number format so that Excel will not convert the numbers to scientific notation.  If you use a 10 digit auto-number then you will not need a special format.

Comment: or just use `=ROW()`

Comment: It will not work. If Name is same for multiple Revision then Name should be one Autogenerated number only.

Comment: @ JNevill - Auto Number depends on Name and Revision. If Name is having multiple Revision then also Auto Number will be one only. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't Name is a unique name already?  Won't sorting the table helps?  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
Sub FixAutoNubmer()
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim num As Double, x As Long
    num = 100000000000#
    Columns("C").NumberFormat = "000000000000"

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For x = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        If dict.Exists(Cells(x, "A")) Then
            Cells(x, "C") = dict(Cells(x, "A"))
        Else
            dict(Cells(x, "A")) = num
            Cells(x, "C") = num
            num = num + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't forget to set `Cells(x, "C") = num` in the case where the value isn't in the dictionary, and you should probably initialise `num = 100000000001#` (and make it a Long?)

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks again.  I get an overflow if I declare num as long.

Comment: Oops - even though I googled VBA data types, I looked at a Visual Basic data types page instead - my apologies.  You had better change that back again.

Comment: @Thomas Inzina i am also getting overflow error. Can you please help me. I have changed to integer but still the same error.
Dim num As Integer, x As Integer

Comment: @James I updated my answer.  It was supposed to be `Double`.  You should consider a 10 digit ID as long.

Comment: @Thomas Inzina Thanks. But still i am getting overflow error.

Comment: Hi experts... any help on this would be very helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Ugh.. num should have been declared as a double.

Comment: Sub FixAutoNubmer()
    Dim dict As Object
    Dim num As Double, x As Double
    num = 100000000000#
    Columns("C").NumberFormat = "000000000000"

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For x = 2 To Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        If dict.Exists(Cells(x, "A")) Then
            Cells(x, "C") = dict(Cells(x, "A"))
        Else
            dict(Cells(x, "A")) = num
            Cells(x, "C") = num
            num = num + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Not working. Run Time Error-16. Expression too complex.

Comment: That is so weird.  Change x back to long: `x As Long` and it will work.  I updated my answer.

Comment: @Thomas Inzina Thanks this time it executed but the Output is not as expected. The Auto Number in Column C should generate based on the Column A and B. If Column A Namen(CA648070ADA7) having same value for different column B revision Value (1,2) then Column C Auto NUmber should have only one value for both the records e.g. 100000000003
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that does not seem possible in excel if it has to be number and not text.

The longer answer is that numbers in Excel can have only up to `15` digits.
The names seem hexadecimal so 12 hexadecimal characters to decimal will be
`16^12 ~ 2.81474977e14` which is 15 digits, **but** `999999999999999/(16^12)` is ~ `3.5527136788` which means that in theory it has space for only up to **3** revisions.
The only alternative I can think of is to store the number as text. 
The [`Hex2Dec`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HEX2DEC-function-8c8c3155-9f37-45a5-a3ee-ee5379ef106e) Excel function can convert only up to 10 hexadecimal characters to a decimal, so it can be used on parts of the name:

```
= B2 & Hex2Dec( Left(A2,6) ) & Hex2Dec( Mid(A2,7,6) )
```

Another alternative might be to convert the hexadecimal string to VBA decimal type:

```
Function HexToDecimal(hexadecimal As String) As String
    HexToDecimal = CDec("&H" & hexadecimal)
End Function
```

and sample use:

```
= HexToDecimal( B2 & A2 )
```

**Update**

I probably misunderstood your question. If the Auto Number is based only on the name, then:

```
= Hex2Dec( Left(A2, 10) ) * 256 + Hex2Dec( Right(A2, 2) )
```

Comment: Auto Number can be anything Test or Number. It also not necessary it has to be 10 digit or 12 digit. Its just example of 12 digit. The Logic is Auto Number should be based on Name and Revision.

Comment: @James then you should give better example and specify that in your question. You keep saying that the Auto Number should be based on Name and Revision, but then you have the same Auto Number for the same Name and different Revision which means that it is based only on the Name.